# Deletion function doing nothing

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am working on a Binary Search Tree for class and have most of my code implemented (I think) correctly, although if I attempt to delete the root node, nothing happens.

Does anyone see a problem with my code?

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
private Node root;
private int size = 0;

public BinarySearchTree(){
    root = null;
}

public BinarySearchTree create(){
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
    return tree;
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public Node getRoot(){
    System.out.println("root: " + root.getData());
    return root;
}

public void insert(String s){
    root = insertHelper(root, s.toLowerCase());
    size++;
}
private Node insertHelper(Node n, String s){
    if(n == null){
        //root is null, make it a new node
        n = new Node(s);
    } else if(s.compareTo(n.getData()) < 0){
        //string is alphabetically less than root
        n.setLeft(insertHelper(n.getLeft(), s));
        n.getLeft().setParent(n);
    } else{
        //string is alphabetically greater than root
        n.setRight(insertHelper(n.getRight(), s));
        n.getRight().setParent(n);
    }
    return n;
}

public void delete(String s){
    deleteHelper(root, s.toLowerCase());
}
private void deleteHelper(Node n, String s){
    if(n == null){
        //nothing to delete
        return;
    }
    //found node to delete
    else if(s.equals(n.getData())){
        System.out.println("DELETED: " + n.getData());
        //check for left subtree
        //if null, replace node-to-be-deleted with
        //right subtree
        if(n.getLeft() == null){
            replace(n, n.getRight());
        } 
        //check for right subtree
        //if null, replace node-to-be-deleted with
        //left subtree
        else if(n.getRight() == null){
            replace(n, n.getLeft());
        } 
        //if it has two subtrees, find minimum value of the
        //right tree and swap the node-to-be-deleted's data with
        //the minimum node's data
        else{
            Node min = n.getRight();
            while(min.getLeft() != null){
                min = min.getLeft();
            }
            //replace with right and reset pointers
            if(min.getParent() != n){
                replace(min, min.getRight());
                min.setRight(n.getRight());
                min.getRight().setParent(min);
            } 
            //replace with left and reset pointers
            else{
                replace(n, min);
                min.setLeft(n.getLeft());
                min.getLeft().setParent(min);
            }
        }
    }
    //if it hasn't been found, recurse left
    else if(s.compareTo(n.getData()) < 0){
        deleteHelper(n.getLeft(), s);
    } 
    //then, recurse right
    else{
        deleteHelper(n.getRight(), s);
    }
}
private void replace(Node x, Node y){
    //if x is the root, set root to y
    if(x.getParent() == null){
        root = y;
    } 
    //if x is a left child, set it's parent's left child to y
    else if(x == x.getParent().getLeft()){
        x.getParent().setLeft(y);
    } 
    //if x is a right child, set it's parent's right child to y
    else{
        x.getParent().setRight(y);
    }
    //if y is not null, set y's parent to be x's parent
    if(y != null){
        y.setParent(x.getParent());
    }
}

public void destroy(){
    //wipe out the tree
    root = null;
    size = 0;
}

public boolean find(String s){
    return findHelper(root, s.toLowerCase());
}
public boolean findHelper(Node n, String s){
    if(n == null){
        System.out.println("Sorry, " + s + " is not in here.");
        return false;
    }  
    if(s.equals(n.getData())){
        System.out.println(s + " is in the tree.");
        return true;
    } else if(s.compareTo(n.getData()) < 0){
        return findHelper(n.getLeft(), s);
    } else{
        return findHelper(n.getRight(), s);
    }
}
}


public class SearchDriver {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchDriver me = new SearchDriver();
    me.doIt();
}

public void doIt(){
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

    tree.insert("marry");
    tree.insert("alpha");
    tree.insert("gamma");
    tree.insert("delta");
    tree.insert("epsilon");
    tree.insert("zeta");
    tree.insert("eta");
    tree.insert("theta");
    tree.insert("iota");
    tree.insert("kappa");
    tree.insert("lambda");
    tree.insert("beta");
    tree.insert("nu");
    tree.insert("xi");
    tree.insert("omicron");
    tree.insert("pi");
    tree.insert("rho");
    tree.insert("sigma");
    tree.insert("tau");
    tree.insert("upsilon");
    tree.insert("phi");
    tree.insert("chi");
    tree.insert("psi");
    tree.insert("omega");
    tree.printInOrder();

    tree.delete("psi");
    tree.printInOrder();

    tree.delete("marry");

    tree.printInOrder();
    tree.printPostOrder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Such issues are usually solver by debugger. If you wont find error, please, post whole code and we will help.

Comment: posted the whole code, i am new to using debuggers, and not exactly sure what i should be looking to do here in Eclipse.

Comment: Worked for me, what post your input sequence.

Comment: just added it in. it also shows what i am printing and "marry" wont leave" :( thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Let me help you:

- Build your program in an [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- Set a breakpoint at the start of your main method
- Start your program in a [debugger](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/compiler.html)
- Step through the code with the scenario where root is being deleted

If you cannot solve this problem with the advice given above, put a comment in this question as to what specifically you were stuck on.  **If you don't take the time now to learn these skills, it will haunt you forever and ever in your programming profession**.

Comment: i am building it in Eclipse, i am specifically stuck on trying to delete the first string that i insert into the tree. for example, if i enter: "marry" "had" "socks" "on" in that order, i will not be able to remove "marry".

Comment: i fully appreciate the fact that i need to learn these skills, that is why i came here for some insight. im not looking for answers, just guidance.

Comment: So when you stepped through the code in the debugger, were all of your expectations met?

Comment: not really, i am very new to eclipse and using debuggers entirely. i have another class "SearchDriver" with my main method, and not so sure what exactly I am looking for. I appreciate the help, I am going to add in the SearchDriver code above.

Comment: Glad to help.  You really should take the time right now to learn how to set a breakpoint and run your program in the debugger.  Set the breakpoint in your main method and step line by line through the code until you reach your function.  Alternatively, you can set the breakpoint at the top of the deleteHelper routine and run in the debugger.

Comment: and what is it that i am look to see? sorry if this is asking too much or a serious n00b question, just looking to learn how to use the tools.

Comment: i have figured out how to set the breakpoint there and step through, but just dont know what i am looking to see for variable values and how that would indicate what to change.

Comment: as you step through the code, look at the values of the variables as well as making sure you hit the conditions you expect to hit -- you're basically playing the code 'live'.

Comment: so i think i have gotten a hang of how to step through and see what is going on, and i am getting into the `if` statement that someone posted below, so that confirms that this is where something isnt working properly, and that is now what i am unable to pinpoint.

Comment: so, TL;DR, thank you for the help with the debugger, now any insight into the logic here?

Comment: which if statement do you enter?  the top level one where n == null?

Comment: no the one that is `if(min.getParent() != n)`.... again really cant express how much i appreciate the help, this is only the second time ive reached out to this site and everyone is super helpful, i did try to take this comment thread to chat, but dont have enough reputation yet i guess. womp womp

Comment: I'll try to debug this today and get back to you.

Comment: my node class is just `Node left; Node right; Node parent;` and their getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with:

```
if (min.getParent() != n) {
      replace(min, min.getRight());
      min.setRight(n.getRight());
      min.getRight().setParent(min);
}
```

This is never replacing n with min so root is never being set to its new value.

Comment: in the delete(String s) method, it is converting s.toLowerCase()

Comment: Ah sorry only saw you post the delete/delete helper methods.

Comment: i THOUGHT the problem is there. i will try to fix it and get back to you.

Comment: baaah this logic is confusing. if i `replace(n, min.getRight())` and am deleting not only "marry" but its entire subtree as well.

Comment: Yeah the problem is in this peace of code. You gotta delete root in that block too.

Comment: just found that out also, with the help of amir above and the debugger. not so sure how to make this work though. :(

Comment: @EugenePavlovsky do you have any ideas as to how i can accomplish that?

Comment: After the replace there I think you just need to do something like `min.setRight(n.getRight()); min.setLeft(n.getLeft()); min.getRight().setParent(min); min.getLeft().setParent(min); root=min;`

Comment: thanks for that! it helped, i think i now need to just add in an if(root = n)